# How can install FEniCS in my PC with ubuntu 18.04 O/S

Tags: 18.04

I bough a brand new PC loaded with Ubuntu 18.04 O/S. Is FEniCS software in Ubuntu PPA?

Comment: FYI the fenics 2017 is packaged in 18.04 LTS - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fenics .

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Personal Package Archives (PPA) version is the latest release of FEniCS. To install FEniCS from the Ubuntu PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fenics-packages/fenics
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends fenics
```

also if you want To install the Python components of FEniCS:

```
pip3 install fenics-ffc --upgrade
```

This will install FFC and its dependencies.

Comment: Please [edit] and describe the steps. One-liners and link only answers are frowned upon here.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I did that , tnx for the suggestion

Comment: I follow all the instructions but :~$ pip3 install fenics -ffc responds like this:

Comment: I followed all the instructions. Instruction pip3 install fenics -ffc did not work. The response was: Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3-pip.  FFC or ffc is not just python has more like Dolfin, for example and more. Help appreciated.

Comment: @batman47 did you install pip3 and after that what happened ??

Comment: Yes. I installed pip3 and from them everything was ok. It started to load a lot of stuff. Thank you. Your help much appreciated. Juan